# Reference request: Oldest books on analytic geometry with unsolved exercises?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, textbook-recommendation, analytic-geometry

Per the title, what are some of the oldest books on analytic geometry out there with unsolved exercises? Maybe there are some hidden gems from before the 20th century out there.

Comment: Have you tried [this](//mathoverflow.net/questions/337524/reference-request-oldest-books-on-algebraic-curves-with-unsolved-exercises#comment845862_338204)?

Comment: (Also, one “[out there](//doi.org/10.1017/S026607840100205X)” might suffice.)

Comment: You ask the same question repeatedly but just change the subject area.  Please consider posting a big-list question "Oldest books in different areas of math with unsolved exercises".  And these don't seem like research-level questions. Consider posting on math.stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here are some late 19th century and early 20th century textbooks on analytic geometry that contain *unsolved* exercises (an example page is shown for each entry). The list is not exhaustive, you can find more by querying [Archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=analytic+geometry&sort=date&page=1) .)

[An elementary treatise on solid geometry,](https://archive.org/details/solidgeometry00aldirich/) by W. Steadman Aldis (1880)

[image]

[Elements of analytic geometry,](https://archive.org/details/elementsofanalyt00newcrich) by Simon Newcomb (1884)

[image]

[Elements of analytic geometry,](https://archive.org/details/elementsofanaly00went) George A. Wentworth (1886)

[image]

[New Analytic Geometry,](https://archive.org/details/cu31924004258137) by Percey F. Smith (1912)

[image]

[Analytic Geometry,](https://archive.org/details/analyticgeometr00colpgoog) by Maria M. Roberts and Julia T. Colpitts (1918)

[image]